# ubuntu boot drops to initramfs and keyboard not working

Tags: 14.04, boot, keyboard, initramfs

My system boots into initramfs and while try to type my keyboard is frozen in initramfs and its not working.While i tried another time same error occur keyboard not working.

Comment: What Ubuntu are you using?  You tagged Ubuntu 14.04, where Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is off-topic as it's EOL, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is off-topic as all ESM's are supported only by Canonical.